ValueError: Cannot Reshape Tensor When Training ENet Model with Discriminative Loss Function
I’m currently working on a lane detection project using instance segmentation and following this tutorial. I’m attempting to train an ENet model with a discriminative loss function, but I'm encountering the following error during training:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sippathamm/Documents/Programming/Projects/LaneDetector/train_model.py", line 272, in <module>
    history = model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train_cat)
  File "/Users/sippathamm/anaconda3/envs/MLDL/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/var/folders/8f/zd3s4vr167zbrffc19_zs48c0000gn/T/__autograph_generated_filex1_6wdpw.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
  File "/var/folders/8f/zd3s4vr167zbrffc19_zs48c0000gn/T/__autograph_generated_filev5ccdt91.py", line 13, in tf__instance_loss
    (_, var_loss, dist_loss, reg_loss) = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(discriminative_loss), (ag__.ld(inst_seg), ag__.ld(instance_label), ag__.ld(embed_size), ag__.ld(img_size)), None, fscope)
  File "/var/folders/8f/zd3s4vr167zbrffc19_zs48c0000gn/T/__autograph_generated_fileszlfxxm7.py", line 48, in tf__discriminative_loss
    (_, _, out_loss_op, out_var_op, out_dist_op, out_reg_op, _) = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).while_loop, (ag__.ld(cond), ag__.ld(body), [ag__.ld(correct_label), ag__.ld(prediction), ag__.ld(output_ta_loss), ag__.ld(output_ta_var), ag__.ld(output_ta_dist), ag__.ld(output_ta_reg), 0]), None, fscope)
  File "/var/folders/8f/zd3s4vr167zbrffc19_zs48c0000gn/T/__autograph_generated_fileszlfxxm7.py", line 32, in body
    (disc_loss, l_var, l_dist, l_reg) = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(discriminative_loss_single), (ag__.ld(prediction)[ag__.ld(i)], ag__.ld(correct_label)[ag__.ld(i)], ag__.ld(feature_dim), ag__.ld(image_shape), ag__.ld(delta_v), ag__.ld(delta_d), ag__.ld(param_var), ag__.ld(param_dist), ag__.ld(param_reg)), None, fscope_2)
  File "/var/folders/8f/zd3s4vr167zbrffc19_zs48c0000gn/T/__autograph_generated_file0j77mdt_.py", line 21, in tf__discriminative_loss_single
    correct_label = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reshape, (ag__.ld(correct_label), [ag__.ld(label_shape)[1] * ag__.ld(label_shape)[0]]), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/Users/sippathamm/anaconda3/envs/MLDL/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/Users/sippathamm/Documents/Programming/Projects/LaneDetector/train_model.py", line 117, in instance_loss  *
        _, var_loss, dist_loss, reg_loss = discriminative_loss(inst_seg, instance_label, embed_size, img_size)
    File "/Users/sippathamm/Documents/Programming/Projects/LaneDetector/train_model.py", line 224, in body  *
        disc_loss, l_var, l_dist, l_reg = discriminative_loss_single(prediction[i], correct_label[i], feature_dim,
    File "/Users/sippathamm/Documents/Programming/Projects/LaneDetector/train_model.py", line 143, in discriminative_loss_single  *
        correct_label = tf.reshape(correct_label, [label_shape[1] * label_shape[0]])

    ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 184320 elements to shape [61440] (61440 elements) for '{{node instance_loss/while/Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](instance_loss/while/strided_slice_1, instance_loss/while/Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [120,512,3], [1] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [61440].

The shapes of my input data are as follows:

X_train: (batch_size, 120, 512, 3)

y_train_cat: (batch_size, 120, 512, 3) (representing one-hot encoded labels)


From the error, it seems like there’s an issue with reshaping tensors within the discriminative loss function. Since this is my first time using a discriminative loss function, I’m having difficulty understanding how to resolve this issue.
Here is the implementation of the discriminative loss function:
def instance_loss(instance_label, net_out, embed_size=3, img_size=(120, 512)):
    k_instance = 1.0
    k_dist = 1.0

    inst_seg = net_out
    _, var_loss, dist_loss, reg_loss = discriminative_loss(inst_seg, instance_label, embed_size, img_size)

    var_loss = var_loss * k_instance
    dist_loss = dist_loss * k_dist
    inst_loss = var_loss + dist_loss

    # print(inst_loss.dtype)

    return inst_loss


def discriminative_loss_single(prediction, correct_label, feature_dim, label_shape,
                               delta_v=0.5, delta_d=3, param_var=1.0, param_dist=1.0, param_reg=0.0):
    ''' Discriminative loss for a single prediction/label pair.
    :param prediction: inference of network
    :param correct_label: instance label
    :feature_dim: feature dimension of prediction
    :param label_shape: shape of label
    :param delta_v: cutoff variance distance
    :param delta_d: curoff cluster distance
    :param param_var: weight for intra cluster variance
    :param param_dist: weight for inter cluster distances
    :param param_reg: weight regularization
    '''

    ### Reshape so pixels are aligned along a vector
    correct_label = tf.reshape(correct_label, [label_shape[1] * label_shape[0]])
    reshaped_pred = tf.reshape(prediction, [label_shape[1] * label_shape[0], feature_dim])

    correct_label = tf.cast(correct_label, dtype=tf.float32)
    reshaped_pred = tf.cast(reshaped_pred, dtype=tf.float32)
    unique_labels, unique_id, counts = tf.unique_with_counts(correct_label)
    counts = tf.cast(counts, tf.float32)
    num_instances = tf.size(unique_labels)

    segmented_sum = tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum(reshaped_pred, unique_id, num_instances)
    segmented_sum = tf.cast(segmented_sum, dtype=tf.float32)
    mu = tf.math.divide(segmented_sum, tf.reshape(counts, (-1, 1)))
    mu_expand = tf.gather(mu, unique_id)

    ### Calculate l_var
    distance = tf.subtract(mu_expand, reshaped_pred)
    distance = tf.norm(distance, axis=1)
    distance = tf.subtract(distance, delta_v)
    distance = tf.clip_by_value(distance, 0., distance)
    distance = tf.square(distance)

    l_var = tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum(distance, unique_id, num_instances)
    l_var = tf.math.divide(l_var, counts)
    l_var = tf.reduce_sum(l_var)
    l_var = tf.math.divide(l_var, tf.cast(num_instances, tf.float32))

    ### Calculate l_dist

    # Get distance for each pair of clusters like this:
    #   mu_1 - mu_1
    #   mu_2 - mu_1
    #   mu_3 - mu_1
    #   mu_1 - mu_2
    #   mu_2 - mu_2
    #   mu_3 - mu_2
    #   mu_1 - mu_3
    #   mu_2 - mu_3
    #   mu_3 - mu_3

    mu_interleaved_rep = tf.tile(mu, [num_instances, 1])
    mu_band_rep = tf.tile(mu, [1, num_instances])
    mu_band_rep = tf.reshape(mu_band_rep, (num_instances * num_instances, feature_dim))

    mu_diff = tf.subtract(mu_band_rep, mu_interleaved_rep)

    # Filter out zeros from same cluster subtraction
    intermediate_tensor = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(mu_diff), axis=1)
    zero_vector = tf.zeros(1, dtype=tf.float32)
    bool_mask = tf.not_equal(intermediate_tensor, zero_vector)
    mu_diff_bool = tf.boolean_mask(mu_diff, bool_mask)

    mu_norm = tf.norm(mu_diff_bool, axis=1)
    mu_norm = tf.subtract(2. * delta_d, mu_norm)
    mu_norm = tf.clip_by_value(mu_norm, 0., mu_norm)
    mu_norm = tf.square(mu_norm)

    l_dist = tf.reduce_mean(mu_norm)

    ### Calculate l_reg
    l_reg = tf.reduce_mean(tf.norm(mu, axis=1))

    param_scale = 1.
    l_var = param_var * l_var
    l_dist = param_dist * l_dist
    l_reg = param_reg * l_reg

    loss = param_scale * (l_var + l_dist + l_reg)

    return loss, l_var, l_dist, l_reg


def discriminative_loss(prediction, correct_label, feature_dim, image_shape,
                        delta_v=0.5, delta_d=1.5, param_var=1.5, param_dist=1.0, param_reg=1.0):
    ''' Iterate over a batch of prediction/label and cumulate loss
    :return: discriminative loss and its three components
    '''

    def cond(label, batch, out_loss, out_var, out_dist, out_reg, i):
        return tf.math.less(i, tf.shape(batch)[0])

    def body(label, batch, out_loss, out_var, out_dist, out_reg, i):
        disc_loss, l_var, l_dist, l_reg = discriminative_loss_single(prediction[i], correct_label[i], feature_dim,
                                                                     image_shape,
                                                                     delta_v, delta_d, param_var, param_dist, param_reg)

        out_loss = out_loss.write(i, disc_loss)
        out_var = out_var.write(i, l_var)
        out_dist = out_dist.write(i, l_dist)
        out_reg = out_reg.write(i, l_reg)

        return label, batch, out_loss, out_var, out_dist, out_reg, i + 1

    # TensorArray is a data structure that support dynamic writing
    output_ta_loss = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,
                                    size=0,
                                    dynamic_size=True)
    output_ta_var = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,
                                   size=0,
                                   dynamic_size=True)
    output_ta_dist = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,
                                    size=0,
                                    dynamic_size=True)
    output_ta_reg = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,
                                   size=0,
                                   dynamic_size=True)
    _, _, out_loss_op, out_var_op, out_dist_op, out_reg_op, _ = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [correct_label,
                                                                                           prediction,
                                                                                           output_ta_loss,
                                                                                           output_ta_var,
                                                                                           output_ta_dist,
                                                                                           output_ta_reg,
                                                                                           0])
    out_loss_op = out_loss_op.stack()
    out_var_op = out_var_op.stack()
    out_dist_op = out_dist_op.stack()
    out_reg_op = out_reg_op.stack()

    disc_loss = tf.reduce_mean(out_loss_op)
    l_var = tf.reduce_mean(out_var_op)
    l_dist = tf.reduce_mean(out_dist_op)
    l_reg = tf.reduce_mean(out_reg_op)

    return disc_loss, l_var, l_dist, l_reg

Below is the workflow code that I am using:
# Load and prepare data
X = np.array([...] , dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array([...] , dtype=np.uint8)

print('> X shape:', X.shape)  # (461, 120, 512, 3)
print('> y shape:', y.shape)  # (461, 120, 512)
print('> Classes:', np.unique(y)) # [0 1 2]

# Split data into training and validation sets
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.143, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

# One-hot encode labels
y_train_cat = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=3)
y_val_cat = to_categorical(y_val, num_classes=3)

# Initialize and compile model
model = ENetBaseModel(input_shape=(512, 120, 3))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              loss=instance_loss,
              metrics=[CategoricalAccuracy()])

# Train model
history = model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train_cat,
                    batch_size=32,
                    epochs=300,
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=callbacks,
                    validation_data=(X_val, y_val_cat),
                    shuffle=False,
                    )

Has anyone experienced a similar issue, or can anyone provide guidance on how to correctly reshape the tensors to avoid this error? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
My assumption is that the issue might be related to the discriminative loss function not being compatible with one-hot encoded labels.
